# Error: "git" command line tool is not installed:

Tags: git

I'm trying to:

```
cordova plugins add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

But I'm getting:

```
Error: "git" command line tool is not installed:
make sure it is accessible on your PATH.
```

So then I do this:

```
npm install -g git
```

And it looks like it installed it here:

```
c:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\git
```

So should add that to my existing path?

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\DLLShared\;C:\AdobeAIRSDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\apache-ant\bin;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\AndroidDevelopmentKit\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;C:\AndroidDevelopmentKit\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools

Or should I add something other than c:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\git?
Because I don't see an executable there.

Comment: `npm install -g git` installed the Git module for nodejs, which is a Javascript extension library that can interface with git. What you want is to install the actual Git software release, which is [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/), and put the path to that in your `PATH` environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the `git` executable. Check how to install it from the Windows section here: [git installation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Windows) or [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/)

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install -g git
```

This will install the NPM package [git](https://www.npmjs.org/package/git) (also known as [node-git](https://github.com/christkv/node-git)). This is not the same as the *real* [Git](http://git-scm.com/) that is available as a command line utility. The former NPM package is essentially a Node JS module to utilize Git functionality. And as the project explains, it also contains some actions natively, but for many others it will need to fall back to the command line utility.

So, you should just install the real [Git](http://git-scm.com/download).

Answer (score 6):

start menu > system properties > system advanced config > environment variables.
go to system variables and find "Path" variable, click on "edit" then go to the end of the value, and a semicolon (;) and paste your git route (mine is: C:\Program Files\Git\bin). save it and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

if you already install git, still you getting problem means me have two solution
1. add path in EV "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" and "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd". Restart machine.

2nd solution is uninstall  and install(https://git-scm.com/downloads) aagin and do step1.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same problem and tried all above solutions but still I was getting same issue for that I checked my "Path" in environment variables and found that it was already having (C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;) in Path and i was adding (C:\Program Files\Git\bin;). So it was creating  a conflict .
Then i removed (C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;) and append (C:\Program Files\Git\bin;) this only in my Path. And close cmd and again type same add plugin command on the same directory and It Worked!!