# Error: Failed to fetch plugin http://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git via git

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am new to the ionic 2 and I wanted to upload the image using firebase database. By following http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-serving-images-with-firebase-storage/ this tutorial that I am doing. When I added the plugin **ionic plugin add http://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git** I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like this:

```
https://www.github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git --save
```

I have tested it and working fine.

[image]

Here is the `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.myfirstapp414454" version="0.0.1">

    <plugin name="com.megster.cordova.FileChooser" spec="https://www.github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git" />

</widget>
```

Comment: how that worked for me then? do you have any firewall restrictions or something like that?

Comment: I am tried what you had tried it is getting error like this
Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://www.github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git
 via git.
Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
        Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessi
ble on your PATH.

Comment: then you have to follow this article first:http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/installation/

Comment: i had downloaded and installed but facing same error

Comment: my project is working but i am not able to install only that plugin remaining plugins i am able to install

Comment: Error: Failed to fetch plugin http://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git via
git.
Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
        Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessi
ble on your PATH.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153078/error-git-command-line-tool-is-not-installed

Comment: already i had tried the question you had send but i am not able to solve by issue

Comment: it seems an issue on your environment.try this after restarting the machine.if you're using any router for internet then restart those too.

Comment: tq bro after restarting my system i am able to install